# Taking Eigen::Vector as a parameter

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to write a function that takes an `Eigen::Vector<T, dim>` as a parameter. However, the following example fails to compile:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

template<class F, typename T, int dim>
void bar(F&& func, const Eigen::Vector<T, dim>& arg1) {
}

template<typename T, int dim>
void foo(const Eigen::Vector<T, dim>& a) {
  return bar([] {}, a);
}

int main() {
  Eigen::Vector<float, 3> v1{ 1.f,2.f,3.f };
  foo(v1);
  return 0;
}
```

This, under Visual Studio 2019, gives me the following error:

```
1>main.cpp(9,10): error C2672:  'bar': no matching overloaded function found
1>main.cpp(14): message :  see reference to function template instantiation 'void foo<float,3>(const Eigen::Matrix<float,3,1,0,3,1> &)' being compiled
1>main.cpp(9,1): error C2784:  'void bar(F &&,const Eigen::Matrix<T,dim,1,|_Rows==&&?:&&_Rows!=?:,_Rows,1> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const Eigen::Matrix<T,dim,1,|_Rows==&&?:&&_Rows!=?:,_Rows,1> &' from 'const Eigen::Matrix<float,3,1,0,3,1>'
1>main.cpp(4): message :  see declaration of 'bar'
```

My questions:

- What is this weird `|_Rows==&&?:&&_Rows!=?:` in the error message?
- What can I do to make the above code compile?

The `bar` function should have `T` and `dim` availabe. I cannot just take `const AnyType& arg1`, because the actual implementation of `bar` depends on compile-time known values `T` and `dim`.

I have seen https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html. I *think* I understand what they are saying, but I am not sure if it applies here. I am taking an actual `Eigen::Vector` as an argument, not an expression.

If there was an expression it would be fine for me, to have it materialized.

Nevertheless, if I try to follow their instruction and just use `ArrayBase<Derived>`, I lose the compile-time information about `T` and `dim`.

Comment: This compiles fine on my machine (g++ 5.4, ubuntu 16.04). I'm using the devel version of Eigen though (v 3.3.90). Not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: @RHertel Thank you for the tip! My g++ 9.1 can compile it too under linux. This may be a problem of Visual Studio and not my code. I would like to get to the bottom of this though, as ultimately I am using Visual Studio in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed looks like an MSVC issue, it compiles fine with gcc >= 4.7, and clang >= 3.5: https://godbolt.org/z/kqoHyO

One possible workaround would be to explicitly write out what `Eigen::Vector` expands to:

```
template<class F, typename T, int dim>
void bar(F&& func, const Eigen::Matrix<T, dim, 1, 0, dim, 1>& arg1) {
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vlvSDP

The weird `|_Rows==&&?:&&_Rows!=?:` looks like MSVC mangled the default value of the `Options` template parameter:

```
          AutoAlign |
                      ( (_Rows==1 && _Cols!=1) ? Eigen::RowMajor
                      : (_Cols==1 && _Rows!=1) ? Eigen::ColMajor
                      : EIGEN_DEFAULT_MATRIX_STORAGE_ORDER_OPTION ),
```

If you want to get to the bottom of this, you should file a bug-report to the MSVC maintainers, maybe using a simplified example like this: https://godbolt.org/z/U_0Sh7 (probably it's possible to reduce this even more).